# pass the js variable variable to html template

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, drupal-7

I have fetched drupal value in  js file.I want to pass the variable in html template.I want to include 'anniversaryCount' to html template.Now I caught

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|.)cbox(.|$)/: Stack overflow
>       at RegExp.test ()

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.one_time_popup = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var anniversaryCount = Drupal.settings.one_time_popup.aniv;
      console.log(anniversaryCount); //prints correct value
      cardTemplate = "<div class='cardTemplate'><span class='birthdayImage'></span><p class='wishes'>Happy Work Anniversary <span id='spl_name'></span> !</p><img src='" + Drupal.settings.publicpath + "/Anniversary_Images/" + anniversaryCount + "Anniversary.jpg'></div>";
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You error have no relation with your code , this error reference to RegExp /(^|.)cbox(.|$)/

Answer (score 0):

with jquery put your html in to the page

> $("#your_elemen_id_where_to_put_html").html(cardTemplate);